# Subtracting a column value which corresponds to a specific value in another column from the every row in that column in R

Tags: r, subtraction, mutate

| Fish_ID | Instance | Success | First_Success | Inst_Diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | -2 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | -1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 4 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 3 |

```
results %>%
  group_by(Fish_ID) %>%
  mutate(Inst_Diff = Instance- Instance[First_Success==1])
```

I want to create a Inst_Diff column. Using instance number where the first success equals to 1 then the ‘Inst_Diff’ is equivalent to: (Instance) - (Instance at at first success). I have more than one Fish_ID. I tried to code above but it gives an error. I would appericate your suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: TYPO? `"fish_ID" != "Fish_ID"`

Comment: FYI when you get an error, _please include it_. Without that, you are requiring us to try your code and assume that any errors/warnings we see are what you have (not always true). In this case, the error `Column \`fish_ID\` is not found` is fairly clear, and it causes me to do a quick pattern-search in the code/data to find what is different.

Comment: Please please please _try_ the code you give us before finishing submission of a question, it can be frustrating hunting down bugs when the code itself has parsing/syntax/other errors that have nothing to do with what you see and need. In this case, now ... there is no error. If you say you have an error with _this_ code, then please prove it.

Comment: You are right! I just did write an example which taken from my data frame but to make it simple, I did not add everything and changed some names. Thank you for the feedback. I will run code with exactly the same name from now on and then post it here.

Comment: You say it errors but I don't see any errors when I try on your code. My guess is that it has something to do with row counts, where having more data will produce more matches than what you have in this sample data. This is one reason why reproducing your error with sample data is both difficult and important. I'm glad you found an answer for this issue.

Comment: I have some missing instances for some Fish_ID and it gives an error for those as far as I understood. But the solution by@Andre Wildberg below worked and it gave NA values for the missing ones but it did not give an error. Error was something like this `Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `Inst_Diff_1 = inst - inst[First_Success_1 == 1]`.
ℹ In group 7: `fish_ID = 13`.` Sorry I am not sure how to write here the error properly taken from R.

Comment: Generally it's best to put the error in the question itself (in a [code block]), not in a comment. But in order to put code with embedded backticks into a comment, use backslash-backtick. For instance: backtick backslash backtick percent in percent backslash backtick backtick results in `\`%in%\``. So for your error, start with a simple backtick, then prepend all internal backticks with backslashes, then end normally with a backtick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach using `first`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Inst_Diff = Instance - first(Instance[Success == 1]), .by = Fish_ID)
  Fish_ID Instance Success First_Success Inst_Diff
1       1        0       0             0        -2
2       1        1       0             0        -1
3       1        2       1             1         0
4       1        3       0             0         1
5       1        4       1             0         2
6       1        5       0             0         3
```